# Missing home menu on left side from Meta Stack Overflow when checking all reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, sidebar

Since the new review look, I am missing the menu

[image: screen shot of left hand menu]

On the left side from all the review queues.

See
[image: screen shot of review queues without menu]

It is no major problem, but it should be fixed.

Comment: This should be posted as an answer to the [Main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) that announces the review queue changes.

Comment: It has [already been reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360502/289905) there.

Comment: I reported it on the MSE release note https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360502/571958. Note that you have the 3 horizontal lines next to the SO logo which open the exact same menu

Comment: My guess is that the new design is the one intended to be on all sites but the current testing period creates this inconsistency

Comment: i don't visit meta stackechange, here i culdn't find it.

Comment: @nbk _“I don’t visit Meta Stack Exchange”_ — You should. That’s where all network-wide bugs are reported.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i have a finite time, for my activities and i spent it on 2 sites from the network, the "problem" is only visible here n Meta and now where else, so far as i can see, so this is the primary point to report it

Comment: On [main], you have the *Featured on Meta* sidebar which has [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues?cb=1)

Comment: We selectively choose to push left nav into the dropdown. It's quite likely that this is intentional to keep the page cleaner and less distracting while reviewing. It also allows the review area to be wider for people who aren't maximizing their screens.

Comment: This was posted as featrue request, because, i am using the question link to go from review directlz t questions, another click is alwazs possible, but ihmo it wuld be better than removing the menu making a dznamic css so that we all can use our mobiles tablets and other appliances, without moving the screen arounfd to find the review options